# Switch gears from TSQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I am trying to take the TSQL below and convert it into LINQ. I'm obviously not very good at this and not sure how to go about doing a join in Linq. My confusion goes a little beyond just the simple expression. In my basic uses my result set is a class that of course represents a table row...but a join would not have this one to one ratio so do I have to create a custom result set?

TSQL:

```
SELECT 
  SimEA.*,
  SimE.*
FROM 
  dbo.SSimEmailsAdressees SimEA

JOIN dbo.SSimEmails SimE ON
SimEA.EmailID = SimE.EmailMsgID

WHERE
 SimEA.UserId = var
```

The closest I have come:

```
this.GetAll<SSimEmails>() 
    .Where(e => e.SSimEmailsAdressees.Any(p => p.UserId.ToString() == usrID));
```

Which of course return an object that is a mimic of the single table being queried. So I need help getting the join added and I'm guessing I'll have to create a return object something like this?

```
this.GetAll<MyJoinResultsObject>......
```

Comment: Is this entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from ea in SimEA
         join e in SimE
         on ea.EmailID equals e.EmailMsgID
     where ea.UserId = userId
         select new { properties you want here or new object based on properties}
```

Comment: Any reason why a person would use the LINQ above over the Iqueryable lambda? For example I was thinking something along the lines of: this.GetAll<MyCustomReturnObject>().Join(....)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should write something like:

```
var q = 
        from SimEA in SSimEmailsAdressees
        where SimEA.UserId = usrID
        join SimE in SSimEmails on SimEA.EmailID equals SimE.EmailMsgID
               into joinSimE
        from SimE in joinSimE.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select new { EmailID = SimEA.EMailID, UserId = SimEA.UserId, OtherField = SimE.OtherField };
```

Comment: why the 'new' in the 'equals' clause? Can't do without it, e.g. `SimEA.EmailID equals SimE.EmailMsgID`?

Comment: @alzaimar Yes, you are right, It is only useful when you have multiple join keys. I fixed it.